# Dictionary Functions : What doesn this mean

Tags: python-3.x

I was learning Python 3 on SoloLearn, and this question came up:
What is the result of this code?

```
primes = {1: 2, 2: 3, 4: 7, 7:17}
print(primes[primes[4]])

The result is : 17
```

---

```
print(primes[4])
gives : 7
```

---

I know it a simple concept, but I never needed such a concept...
Thanks

Comment: If you understand `primes[4]` and why it outputs `7`, you should also be able to understand why `primes[primes[4]]` outputs `17`. It is the exact same concept.

Answer (score 3):

Well,

```
prime[4]
```

evaluates to

```
7
```

because `7` is the value corresponding to the key `4`.

Breaking this down

```
prime[prime[4]]
```

becomes

```
prime[7]
```

which is

```
17
```

since, once again, `17` is the value corresponding to the key `7` of your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
primes = {1: 2, 2: 3, 4: 7, 7:17}
```

Where primes is a `dict` with key-value paired elements in it.

```
print(primes[4])   # 7
```

Means, print the value of dict with key `4`, i.e. `7`:

```
print(primes[primes[4]])   # 17
```

Where, it means print the value of dict with the key `primes[4]` which is `7`, i.e. it becomes `primes[7]` which results in `17`